# Hosted Backup Solution for a customer

Tags: linux, windows, backup, rsync

I have a potential customer who wants a hosted managed backup solution. Their server is running Windows.

Does anyone know of any software (open source is preferred, but free for commercial use is ok) that will allow me to make incremental backups from a Windows server to a remote Linux box? Restoring files should be easy as well. I also need built-in encryption

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but it is inexpensive for what you get.

I've used [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/) to backup to an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) account.